# display the song name jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a list of songs i play in my website,i want to be able to display the current song name playing ,i have this code which have play ,pause,next,back,which works fine,but i need to edit it to display the song name

```
    <body>
                <a class="btn" href="#" id="play" style="background-color:black">Play </a> 

                <a  class="btn"  href="#"  style="background-color:black" id="pause">Pause</a>
                <br>

                <a  class="btn"  href="#" style="background-color:black" id="skip">Next </a> 

                <a  class="btn"  href="#"  style="background-color:black" id="previous">Back</a>

 <audio    preload="metadata" tabindex="0" controls autoplay type="audio/mpeg"   class="audio-player" src="dz.mp3"></audio>

          <audio  class="audio-player" src="song2.mp3"></audio>

        <audio  class="audio-player" src="song3.mp3"></audio>

            <body>
```

and this is my script

```
<script>
var x = $(".audio-player").length;
var z = 0;
var songName = $("audio[name]")

$("#play").click(function(){
    $(".audio-player")[z].play();
    $("#song-name").text(songName);
    $("#song-name").show();
})
$("#pause").click(function(){
    $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
    $("#song-name").hide();
})
$("#skip").click(function(){
    $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
    z++;
    if (z >= x) z = 0;
    $(".audio-player")[z].play();
    $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
    $("#song-name").text(songName);
})




$("#previous").click(function(){
    $(".audio-player")[z].pause();
    z=z-1;
    if (z >= x) z = 0;
    $(".audio-player")[z].play();
    $(".audio-player")[z].currentTime = 0;
    $("#song-name").text(songName);
})
</Script>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking.  Do you just need a div or a span element with id = "song-name"?

Comment: why your code has two <body> tag?

Comment: you mean the name of the song which is metadata to the file? Is it possible for it to be loaded beforehand as an attribute to `<audio>`?

Comment: exactly ,i want to display each song name that is currently playing

Comment: i meant</body> sorry

Answer (score 0):

Add a new `div` where you want the song name to appear:

```
<div id="song_name"></div>
```

Add this to javascript:

```
$('#song_name').append(songName);
```

You might need to wrap that in a `ready` function as well.

Alternatively, it looks like you have something to show the song name in your code already: `$("#song-name").show();` However, I'm not seeing a `div` with the ID `song-name`. You should just be able to add this `div` to your existing HTML.